# create-vueで作成したばかりのtsconfig.jsonにエラーが出てしまう

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

npm init vue@latest のコマンドでプロジェクトを作成し、
ローカル環境立ち上げまでは完了でき、ページの表示は問題ないのですが、
tsconfig.jsonで「コンパイラ オプション 'preserveValueImports' が不明です。」というエラーが出てしまいます。原因と、解決方法をご教示いただきたいです。

一度プロジェクトのフォルダを削除し、もう一度npm init vue@latestで作り直してみましたが最初から同じエラーが出ます。

tsconfig.jsonのコードは以下になります。

```
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.web.json",
  "include": ["env.d.ts", "src/**/*", "src/**/*.vue","./src/@types/**/*.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },

  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/tsconfig/issues/6